# ASP .net core endpoint configuration

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, asp.net-core

I have a question about configuring endpoints in ASP .Net core.
I have action in controller- HttpGet JsonResult GetList(). It returns json string, it's display it on view, and json string is in Network Response, so I can reach it thorugh JS.

 That's my GetList():

```cs
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetList(int GetListId)
        {
            SavedList = GetListId;
            List<string> Products = new List<string>();
            List<string> currentList = new List<string>();
            using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                currentList = db.ProductLists.Where(w => w.ListId == GetListId).Select(p => p.Product.Name).ToList();
                foreach (var item in currentList)
                {
                    Products.Add(item);
                }
            }
            List<OfflineProduct> ListToCache = new List<OfflineProduct>();
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            for (int i = 0; i < currentList.Count; i++)
            {
                var Prod = new OfflineProduct();
                Prod.ID = i;
                Prod.Name = currentList[i];
                Prod.Done = false;
                ListToCache.Add(Prod);
            }
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListToCache);

            return Json(json);
        }
```

I'm getting some elements from database, and creating list based on it. Serializing data to json, and return it. The problem is, I'm getting JSON string on page, not formatted correctly data. 

 I have Vue View, that is ready to get this JSON data, but I don't know how can I send data directly to Vue View (for example ./wwwroot/SavedOfflineList.html).

My Vue vue is tested, I mean I was using it for static data. That's my view:

```
   <h4>Last Saved List</h4>


    <div id="app">
        <h2>Lista vue:</h2>
        <ol>
            <li v-for="item in items">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           v-on:change="toggle(item)"
                           v-bind:checked="item.Done">

                    <del v-if="item.Done">
                        {{ item.Name}}
                    </del>
                    <span v-else>
                        {{ item.Name }}
                    </span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    var objArray = [];
    async function fetchItems() {
        fetch('/GetList/').then(Response => {
            return Response.json();
        }).then(data => {




            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var newObj = { Name: data[i].Name, ID: data[i].ID, Done: data[i].Done };

            objArray.push(newObj);

                    }
            if (objArray.length != 0) {
                        console.log('have some items');
            }


            console.log(objArray);

        return objArray;   
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })

    }
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            items: [

            ]
        },
        created() {
            this.getItems();
        },
        methods: {
            toggle: function (item) {
                item.Done = !item.Done
            },
            getItems: async function () {
                this.items = await fetchItems();
                this.items = objArray;
            }
        }
    });




</script>
<style>
```

When I'm moving to this GetList page I have URL like: /Offline/GetList?GetListId=36, and I can read json data as I mentioned from response or from page content.

I've read some articles about endpoints, but still I don't know how can I send HttpGet to html view from wwwroot.

I've tested it on static files and it works:

[image: vue]

Thanks for reading and help!

Comment: Could you try to explain better which is your problem?

Comment: The problem is about implementing Vue component, that would render json for me. At this moment I'm just getting json string, when i click button. GetList() is onclick event in View. When I'm clicking it, it should take List, serialize it to json and use this json to create view.

Comment: I've added screen how should it works, when it gets good json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just return the `ListToCache` without extra serialization.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetList(int GetListId)
    {
        SavedList = GetListId;
        List<string> Products = new List<string>();
        List<string> currentList = new List<string>();
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            currentList = db.ProductLists.Where(w => w.ListId == GetListId).Select(p => p.Product.Name).ToList();
            foreach (var item in currentList)
            {
                Products.Add(item);
            }
        }
        List<OfflineProduct> ListToCache = new List<OfflineProduct>();

        for (int i = 0; i < currentList.Count; i++)
        {
            var Prod = new OfflineProduct();
            Prod.ID = i;
            Prod.Name = currentList[i];
            Prod.Done = false;
            ListToCache.Add(Prod);
        }

        return Json(ListToCache);
    }
```

This will generate json response.Besides, the property name is case sensitive for fetch response data.You'd better check the json,generally, it will be

```
var newObj = { Name: data[i].name, ID: data[i].id, Done: data[i].done }
```

Comment: Ok, I've add new cshtml View, where I'm calling GetList Method. And I have jsonData in response.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to replace your script tag with this?

```js
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            items: []
        },
        created() {
            this.getItems();
        },
        methods: {
            toggle: function (item) {
                item.Done = !item.Done
            },
            getItems() {
                fetch('/GetList/').then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => this.items = data)
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Check the Network tab from the Inspector to check that the server is responding what do you want.

Comment: The problem is, that my script doesn't work with dynamic data. I mean when im clicking button next to the list, im getting "/Offline/GetList?GetListId=36" this url, and there is no vue or something.